# How would I find the last instance of a string in a sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a google sheets function to find the cell address corresponding to the last occurrence of the string in A13 ("Treeckosaurus") in all the rows and columns above (A2:D12). I tried using a combination of hlookup and vlookup (since google sheets doesn't have an xlookup function) but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know how I could find the cell address (D12) dynamically?

[image: Sheet for reference]

So far, I have tried incorporating a COUNTIF function into the lookup formula but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated :)
Thank you!

Comment: Make up your mind. Excel or Google sheets. The solutions will be different. If you can't use Xlookup, then you seem to be using Google sheets. In that case, don't tag with Excel.

Comment: Apologies. Right now I’m going to stick to Google Sheets.

Comment: Then remove the Excel tag, because that is wasting Excel experts' time.

Comment: @raoyourboat Please don't mind her, just take care with your tags.

Comment: Done. Do you know of a way to work around the problem I keep running into in the question? @Enzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little bit stress but will work. Try-

```
=ArrayFormula(ADDRESS(MAX(index(IF(A1:D13="Treeckosaurus",ROW(A1:D13),""),,MAX(IF(A1:D13="Treeckosaurus",COLUMN(A1:D13),"")))),MAX(IF(A1:D13="Treeckosaurus",COLUMN(A1:D13),""))))
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for so many hours haha

Comment: @raoyourboat Glad to know!