# Find the last column that contains given content

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know what the column letter (or index) of the last column with a given value is. What formula can I use in Google Sheets to achieve this.

For example:

Using this data.

| ID | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Values | A | B | Q |
|  | B | A | B |
|  | T |  | T |
|  | Z |  |  |

If I give the formula the input `A` it should output the letter or index for the column with ID 1 because `A` appears in that column, but not in the one column to the right of it.

If I give the formula the input `B`, `Q` or `T` it should output the letter or index for the column with ID 2 because all of those appear in the last column of data.

If I give the formula the input `Z` it should output the letter or index for the column with ID 0 because `Z` only appears in the first column of data.

Some background in case anyone's interested:
I'm using a similar spreadsheet to track which unit tests fail in a given run, so, in the example above, the IDs in the header row would be the IDs of the runs, and the letters in the values rows would be the names of the tests that failed in that run. What I want to know is the last time a given test failed, so we can know if that test is still failing periodically, or if it has been reliably fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I find the last instance of a string in a sheet in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463534/how-would-i-find-the-last-instance-of-a-string-in-a-sheet-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=chooserows(tocol(index(if(indirect("C2:"&rows(A:A))=A2,C1:1,)),1,1),-1)
```

- *Adjust the formula as per your sheet design/ranges*

[image]

Comment: This works really well. I don't understand a lot of the layers completely, but I really like they way you've used `ROWS` to avoid needing any arbitrarily large values to capture the full range (though it took me a while to work out what that was doing). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CHOOSEROWS(TOCOL(IF(A3=B2:D,B1:D1,),1,1),-1))
```

Assuming the value is A3, the range is B2:D and the header is B1:D1.

Comment: I don't understand all of this, but it's working exactly as I want it to. Thank you.